# AWS Cloudwatch dashboard custom time range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want each of my graphs on the cloudwatch dashboard to show graphs for different time ranges e.g RAM to show 2 weeks, DISK 4 weeks, etc. Everytime i refresh they revert to auto 3 hours. How can I ensure each graph shows different time range

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible within the same dashboard and you would need to create multiple dashboards to accommodate your requirement.

In CloudFormation, the timeframe is set in the `DashboardBody` property using `start`, which affects the whole dashboard and not the individual widgets.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CloudWatch-Dashboard-Body-Structure.html